# Finding text in a large Json file

Tags: c++, json, file, search, mmap

I have a JSON file which looks like this

```
{
            "ID": "4",
            "samples": [
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "1"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "2"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "3"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "4"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "5"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "6"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "7"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "8"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "9"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "10"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "11"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "12"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "13"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "14"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "15"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "16"
            },
            {
                "value": 2000,
                "timeStamp": "17"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This sample array can be very huge. I need to find the `value` for any given `timestamp`. Since JSON file can be huge , I cannot load it all the file content into the main memory and parse it using `rapidjson` or another JSON C++ libs.

I try to open it with `mmap` function and obtain the pointer to the starting of the file. But the issue is how to reach to particular `timestamp` and obtain the `value`. `Timestamp` always occur in sorted order. Linear searching over huge character array is not time efficient. May be binary search can work but I don't know how can I apply over this data.

Any other technique like caching of file offset or other thing can also help.

Format of JSON file is text.

Comment: I know this might be a little late but one of the good things here is that the timestamps occur in a sorted order. Leverage that to break the file into multiple smaller pieces as a step at the beginning. Then continue with the binary search idea you have. You could probably fit the file into memory and make it really fast.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is too big then just do it manually as you suggested yourself using binary search.
First, find out what's the file size, value of the first `timeStamp` and last `timeStamp`. And then simply position file read pointer to the middle of the file and then read char by char until you find `{` and from that point read your `value` and `timeStamp`. Then based on `timeStamp` that you read you can decide in what direction you need to continue your "binary" search.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I will surely try this. One more thing , I am using strstr function to search desired text inside char array.Is there any other way to accomplish this with higher time optimization

Comment: Yes, strstr would be ok for this task if you need to search for `"timeStamp": ` from any random position in a mmaped file. You may as well use `strstr` if you read like 256 bytes from random location in your file and then search within this buffer for your `"timeStamp": `

Answer (score 1):

rapidjson supports [sax parsing](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html).  This doesn't load completely in memory and makes more sense than parsing text.

Answer (score 0):

Either parse the text file yourself (which could be faster if you can optimize for a very specific format), or search for a streaming JSON parsing library.  Then break out out of the parser when you find the element you want.

(Note that asking for a recommendation of such a library is *explicitly* off-topic for Stack Overflow).